# How handle BackupHelper and SQLites additional files

Tags: android, sqlite, backup

I'm currently developing a BackupHelper for the databases of my Android apps. The method `Context.databaseList()` reports the names of all databases that do belong to my app. But I do experience a lot of additional files beside the main SQLite database files (e.g.):

- database.db
- database.db-journal
- database.db-shm
- database.db-wal

All Android docs tell about a single database file per database but this information seems to be outdated.

Is it save to store all those files with the BackupHelper?

Will SQLite work with these files on all Android platforms after a restore?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some Googling and found some info about the other files:

> database.db-journal

SQLite by default creates the journal file at the start of a transaction, which is a good thing. Normally it deletes the file upon commit.

You can change this behavior to simply truncate the file (no create/delete necessary) or to zero it, via a PRAGMA sql command. Not all options may be supported on your version of SQLite.

```
PRAGMA journal_mode = DELETE | TRUNCATE | PERSIST | MEMORY | OFF
```

Write operations are normally not completed until you COMMIT, which is implemented by truncating, deleting, or invalidating the journal.

If this behavior is new, I have no explanation for why it might have changed, other than perhaps an upgrade of SQLite changed default behavior, or has become more sophisticated by not reopening the journal for every transaction.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633274/what-causes-a-journal-file-to-be-created-in-sqlite)

> database.db-shm 
>   database.db-wal

These are temporary files created by SQLite. If you are manually deleting the main db you should probably delete these too. From what I can gather the WAL is a replacement for the rollback journal that enables SQLite to rollback changes when a transaction fails. How SQLite uses them and why they are kept around for so long is up to the authors of SQLite but in general SQLite seems pretty rock solid so I wouldn't worry too much about them. For more info take a look here:

http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#walindexformat

These files are a new feature of SQLite 3.7.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778723/what-are-the-db-shm-and-db-wal-extensions-in-sqlite-databases)

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks. So it's save to backup all files with the pattern "database.db*" and restore them all later?

Comment: I have not done something like that so I am to sure about it but it looks like they are temporary files used for uncommitted changes and rollback so you can avoid backing up these files. I would suggest trying out with only backing up the `.db` file and see if you can restore the Database with only this file...

Comment: At least the wal file is required. I did test with a customer months ago because he couldn't see all entries in a backup database. What we found out is that wal is no traditional log file. Instead it appends committed (!!!) entries to the wal file only and transfers them to the main file only if a threshold/checkpoint has reached. I think I will backup everything I find ...