# Android log in authentication failled

Tags: android

I am creating an application with registration and alert login modules. That is working fine. After some 10 or 15 users registered, I tried to login got a message like user authentication failed & I am getting some error logs in eclipse. Also, one new file 'test.db-journal' has been created in the same folder of 'test.db', but I am creating test.db file only.

I'm creating table with this code:

```
  MySQL = "create table users(id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, users TEXT not null);";
  myDb.execSQL(MySQL);
```

I don't know why it happened. Will you please tell me the reason or solution.
Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: Could you post the the error logs and authentication code, without that we won't really be able to help.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633274/what-causes-a-journal-file-to-be-created-in-sqlite) explains the creation of "db-journal" files.