# Why an sqlite journal file is creating when my app is loaded (on select)

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

My app is using CoreData with SQLite, and I recently noticed that with a big database (240MB) it takes some time to load.

I discovered that during load a journal file is created then removed.
Reading this post : [What causes a journal file to be created in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633274/what-causes-a-journal-file-to-be-created-in-sqlite), it indicates that a journal is created when a transaction begin to be able to rollback.

In my case I only do a select (no update or insert), so I don't understand why this journal file is created.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Thierry

Comment: I would guess that Core Data is doing some stuff.

Comment: You could set the "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3" launch argument. Perhaps that gives some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data touches objects when you fetch them.  There is internal versioning going on inside of Core Data that we do not have direct access to.  It uses this information for merging, staleness, etc.

Short answer, it is `SEP` (Somebody else's problem) and is internal to Core Data.

Comment: In fact, you kinda have to hide behind a tree then peek out to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Use WAL mode. THis will avoid the huge journal created by default. In WAL mode, the journal is created but it size is according that you need. In you case, it will be minimal since you're not writing a lot.
Just execute the query: `PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;` once when creating the DB. If is executed after creating might throw an error if a previous DB exists.
Note that WAL is not compatible with previous journal types and is supported from 3.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. My problem what with NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption.
When opening Store I add this :

[NSNumber numberWithBool:appHasBeenUpdated], NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption

appHasBeenUpdated is set to YES only when a new update has been installed. The problem is that a vacuum is done each time I open data store even if appHasBeenUpdated is set to NO.